# How to prevent class duplication in a mono repo that uses tailwindcss for UI and frontend both?

Tags: tailwind-css, vite, monorepo, pnpm

I have a pnpm mono repo project with two packages: `ui` and `frontend`. I use the same config (copy/paste) for both packages. When I build the project, the `ui` package is built first, and its classes are generated. Then, the `frontend` package is built while using the CSS from the `ui` package.

The problem is that CSS classes are duplicated at this point. If I use the `mb-2` class in both the `ui` and `frontend` packages, CSS will be generated for both packages.

How can I prevent this from happening? I want the same classes to be generated only once.

Comment: I have the same situation. When I use N packages that uses tailwind in a app, seems like this is being duplicated. I did try with peerDependencies, but nothing seems to be working. Looks like when building the apps, all those references to tailwind are shipped with the package. I'm trying to look if there is anything that I can apply or some config that can be setted in order to prevent this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think we can do anything at this point except having a prefix in your package specific tailwind config but still they will be duplicated with different names. And this is valid because both of the projects can be hosted seperately.